# String Editor (not functioning correctly)

Tags: c, string, function, strncpy

I'm new to C and have been set the following problem. I am to write a program where a string can be entered and stored, I should then enter two integer values which will then be used to remove characters from the string, afterwards the result should be printed. Once the program works it should be converted into a function.

I have created a program that will split the entered string into two strings which store the chars I want to keep in two buffers, afterwards the two strings are concatenated to give the resultant edited string. The problem I am having is that when I print the edited string I get random characters at the end and sometimes in between the two strings and I think it's because the strings are not being null terminated correctly. I hope that someone is able to help, Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{

    char string [25];
    char buffer1 [25];
    char buffer2 [25];
    int start;
    int remove;
    int i;
    int finish;
    int size;
    int numbercopy;
    int A, B, C;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(string);
    printf("\nEnter a starting character position: ");
    scanf("%d", &start);
    printf("\nHow many characters would you like to remove? ");
    scanf("%d", &remove);


    finish = (start+remove);
    size = strlen(string);
    numbercopy = (size-finish);

    strncpy(&buffer1[0], &string[0], start);
    buffer1[start] = '\0';
    strncpy(&buffer2[0], &string[finish], numbercopy);
    buffer2[numbercopy] = '\0';
    A = strlen(buffer1);
    B = strlen(buffer2);
    C = (A+B);
    strcat(buffer1, buffer2);buffer1[C] = '\0';


    for (i=0; i<25; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", buffer1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a string, you do not need to print it character by character. Also, the loop indicates that only 25 char strings will be printed. If a string (`buffer1`) is shorter in length(<25), garbage values will be printed, if a string is is larger (>25), some `chars` will not be printed.

Change this:

```
for (i=0; i<25; i++)
{
printf("%c", buffer1[i]);
}
```

to this: 
    `printf("%s", buffer1);`